# Any studies on authority influence in non-expertise area? (e.g., police captain giving medical advice)?

Tags: expertise

I'm just curious if authority influence, even if a little, carries over to areas in which the authority is not an expert.  Like a doctor giving advice about fashion or best kind of car to buy, etc.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't celebrities give advice on everything? So, yeah, it probably works to some extent.

Comment: Somewhat related to the [halo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_effect) cognitive bias. You could potentially find some related studies there and answer your own question when you deem them relevant.